# C++ read large file and save it to a string and remove specific random words

Tags: c++

I was trying to find a way for read a semi-large file (130 MB) and save it into a string fast and remove all random words in the string, like this:

```
File.txt:
0x0239183 (10): Hello
0x0039123 (1): Test
...
```

The only word that the program should take is the one after the 2 points, not counting the space, for example ("Hello" & "Test" in this case).

I tried with this code:

```
fstream f(legitfiles.c_str(), fstream::in );
string s;
while(getline( f, s, '\0')){
    size_t space_pos = s.find(" ");    
    if (space_pos != std::string::npos) {
        s = s.substr(space_pos + 1);
    }
}
cout << s << endl;
f.close();
```

But when I start the program the only word that remove is the first of the first line.

```
Output File.txt:
 (10): Hello
0x0039123 (1): Test
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
while(getline(f, s)){
    size_t space_pos = s.rfind(" ") + 1;

    cout << s.substr(space_pos) << endl;
}
```

Note that the call to `std::getline` relies upon its default delimiter, and the `std::string` method used to find the correct position to slice the substring from is [`std::string::rfind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind).